# opening a web page in php

Tags: php, html

I want to open "product.htm" page if the product id value is not empty. I don't know how to do this. I am not finding  the solution for this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

product.php:

```
<?php

 if ( empty($_POST["product_id"]) || empty($_POST["price"]) )
         { 
         echo (" you must enter the values for both fields ");
         }
  else
         {
        // here i want to open product.htm if product id and price both are given         
         } 
?>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: have a look at `http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php` and at `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php` (you should do something like `include product.htm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "Open" you could mean `include('product.htm')` or `Header: Location('product.htm')` But i'm assuming one of these will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You could just require the page contents, or echo some javascript that will open a popup if thats what you want.

To show product.html in the current page:

```
require 'product.html';
```

To open it in a popup:

```
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.open('product.html');
</script>

<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) PHP function.